# Dialogflow values are stored in wrong parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow intent which includes different parameters. Although parameter names are unique, in some cases values are stored in wrong parameters and not in their own parameter.

[1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMWWz.png)

[2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2iyE.png)

[3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhRbW.png)

[4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0jwI.png)

Image 1.png shows my intent and its "User Says" sentences.As you can see in 2.png, I have a VarName user defined entity for each variable name.Now in 3.png I try dialogflow by writing "Change Loan Term to 20". But as you can see in 4.png instead of putting 20 in "loan-term" parameter, dialogflow puts "Loan Term" value in "years-to-average-principal" which is wrong parameter for this sentence.

I hope I could make it clear.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you update your question with some screenshots of example Intents that are causing this problem? And what you are saying, what you are expecting, and what you're actually seeing in these cases?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention.I tried a lot to upload screenshots but unfortunately I couldn't.How should I do it?

Comment: First of all - update your question. Don't post it as an answer. This isn't a forum. Second - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images has the documentation for the editor, but the easiest way is to click on the Image icon in the editor and then use it to upload the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have updated my original question with screenshots.Now would you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two sample phrases that, from Dialogflow's perspective, match the exact same kind of inputs. By assigning a portion of a phrase to a parameter, you're basically saying that this part of the phrase can be replaced by anything that matches the parameter's Entity type.

So the phrase "Change Years to Average Principal to 5" can be thought to match something like `Change @VarName to @sys.number`. But the phrase "Change Loan Term to 30" also matches that.

You have several solutions, depending on how you are doing fulfillment and processing these numbers.

**Solution 1: Use different Intents**

Instead of making one Intent that lets you change all the possible variables, create multiple Intents that capture phrases the way people would express them and tie your backend to handle each intent specifically. So you might have one Intent that looks like this

[image]

and another Intent that looks like this

[image]

In your fulfillment, you'd check which Action was triggered to determine which value to adjust and then check the parameter to see how to adjust it - if a number was set, you'd use that number, otherwise you might adjust it by the percentage. You could add other values for other phrases if you wanted to do relative adjustments.

**Solution 2: Use generic value parameters**

Similar to solution 1, instead of naming each value parameter after the attribute you want to adjust, you'll just have a few generic ones (percent value, number, etc) plus the parameter to determine the attribute (your `VarName` parameter and Entity type).

The Intent is easier to specify, but on the back end, you'll need to determine if the user has specified an value parameter that doesn't make sense for the attribute (such as the user specifying a percentage for changing the Term) and generate an error. It might look something like this:

[image]

**Solution 3: Combine the two**

You can use whatever parameter names you want, of course. By default, it names the parameters after the type, because that's nice and generic. So you'd use the Action to figure out what to set, and then the generic names to figure out how to set or adjust it.

Those might look something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks for your complete answer. I had no experience with this matter. Your words were really helpful and instructive.

Comment: Hope it helps! If it does, accepting and/or upvoting the answer are always appreciated.

Comment: Hi dear Prisoner.I used your above second suggestion and it worked well for me,but I have another question. What should I do if I have to write a sentence like this as a User Says :" Change down payment to 40% and interest rate to 56%". In my case both "down payment" and "interest rate" parameters are set to 45% which is the first value for "percentage" value. How can I manage this combined sentences in a single intent?

Comment: New questions on stack overflow are best asked as just that - new questions.

Comment: I asked it here and not as a new question because it is related to my above question and your above solutions.

Comment: It is, however, a vastly different question with what needs to be considered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488991/multiple-dialogflow-commands-asked-at-same-time

Comment: And sorry if I wasn't clear - you'd asked a question, it was answered, and accepted. Even if you're expanding the original question, asking it as a new question is useful because it captures the difference between the question, exposes the question to people who would look for questions that *haven't* been answered already, and makes it easier for other people who may have similar questions to search for and find them later.