# Multiple Dialogflow commands asked at same time

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an Action where the user can set values of different parameters. Currently this is implemented something like this, and it works well:

[image]

Now I want to make the conversation less robot-like and more flexible, so I would like to allow users to set or change more than one value at a time. They should be able to say things like

> Change the Interest Rate to 4% and the Term to 15 years.

or

> Change the Interest Rate to 4%, the Term to 15 years, and the Years to Average Principal to 3.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but none of them are great, and all of them have issues of some sort when you try to scale them. (So they might work well for two or three parameters entered, but they probably won't work well for more than that.)

(It is worth noting, just for reference, that the Assistant itself has only recently started accepting more than one instruction at a time. But it only handles two, and this doesn't work for all commands.)

**Add phrases with additional parameters**

With this solution, you would supplement the phrases you have that collect one parameter with a similar set of phrases that collect two parameters. And then another set that also collect three parameters. You should be able to do these all as a single Intent and, in your fulfillment, determine which ones have been set.

It might look something like this:

[image]

That looks like it starts getting complicated, doesn't it? You need to list each combination of absolute values and percentages. If you have other types, you need to include each of those combinations as well. That starts getting unwieldy for 3 possible parameters, and certainly is above that. You also run the risk that it might get confused about which parameter should be set with which value (I haven't tested this - it is a theoretical concern).

**Add an optional continuation phrase and handle that recursively**

You can also treat this as the user saying "set a value, and then do something else" and treat the "do something else" part as another statement made to Dialogflow. The Intent might look something like this:

[image]

You can implement the "another statement made to Dialogflow" using the Dialogflow API. With Dialogflow V1, you'd use the [Query endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query). With Dialogflow V2, you'd use the [detectIntent endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent). In either case, you'd send the `additional` part of the query (if the user said something) and would get back the results from that. You'd add the resulting message from the call to the message from setting the current set of values and send the whole thing back.

As a recursive call, however, this does take up time. Since the initial call to Dialogflow really needs to be answered within 5 seconds, every additional call to Dialogflow (and then to your fulfillment) needs to be handled as quickly as possible. But even so, you probably won't be able to handle more than 2 or 3 of these before things time out on the front end.

It also runs the risk (or benefit) that other intents besides the `edit.attribute` Intent might be called in the "additional" portion. If you want to limit the risk of this, you could set a context to make sure that only Intents that have that incoming context would be called.

**Summary**

This really isn't an easy problem to solve. On one hand, you have the problem of having to list out every combination. On the other hand, recursion takes time, and you don't have a lot of time to process everything. In both cases, there is a real possibility of the phrase being understood incorrectly and you'll need to figure out error handling in the case where some values have been changed and others haven't.

You may need to experiment a lot, and the results may still not be satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

> You can implement the "another statement made to Dialogflow" using the
>   Dialogflow API. With Dialogflow V1, you'd use the [Query endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query).
>   With Dialogflow V2, you'd use the [detectIntent endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent). In either
>   case, you'd send the additional part of the query (if the user said
>   something) and would get back the results from that. You'd add the
>   resulting message from the call to the message from setting the
>   current set of values and send the whole thing back.
>
> As a recursive call, however, this does take up time. Since the
>   initial call to Dialogflow really needs to be answered within 5
>   seconds, every additional call to Dialogflow (and then to your
>   fulfillment) needs to be handled as quickly as possible. But even so,
>   you probably won't be able to handle more than 2 or 3 of these before
>   things time out on the front end.

The first thing that came to mind after reading those two paragraphs was batch requests. 
A batch request allows a client application to pack multiple API calls into a single HTTP request (this batching technique is also known as a multi-part request).

Many Google APIs support a batch endpoint and I was able to verify that DialogFlow has a batch endpoint by checking its [API Discovery document](https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2). This batch endpoint is not formerly documented in DialogFlow's API reference but you can leverage the documentation of other APIs ([like this one](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)) to get a feel for how it works. [This link should also be instructive now that the global batch endpoint is no longer supported](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html).

Assuming your queries are independent (ie. they don't rely on the results of other queries) you should be able to use a batch request to fetch more data.

Comment: Good thinking! Although the batch operations in the discovery document appear to just be for creating/updating Entities and Intents. Not for detecting them. (I am happy to be wrong on this point, however.)

Comment: @Prisoner Those are not the batch endpoint. 
This is `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/batch`. Its a combination of the `rootUrl` and the `batchPath` properties in the Discovery document(scroll down to the bottom). The batch endpoint is used for `multipart` HTTP requests.