# Two or more identical parameters in one sentence

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow intent which includes different parameters.Shown as below:

[1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67yWF.png)

I set generic "number" for all number parameters such as "Years to Average Principal" and generic "percentage" for all percentage parameters.Like this:

[2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlOyI.png)

When I say something like "Change vacancy rate to 56%" or "change Years to Average Principal to 5", it works well.But when I say a sentence which includes two or more parameters with same type, it sets the first value for all parameters.I used the "Change depreciation percentage to 30% and down payment to 45%" phrase and the result is following images:

[3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU8gW.png)
[4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSuOM.png)

As I have to use only one intent and one action,would you please help me what should I do to have separate values for different parameters?

I hope I could make it clear. Thanks in advance,

Comment: What phrase were you using in your example for 3.png? Can you also show the list of parameter settings under the Action section?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my above question with what you have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good try using the "is list" setting for a parameter! Unfortunately, you only set it for one of the parameters, so it treated that as the list and then used the first matching value for the other parameters since both matched the rule for `percentage`. If one was for `percentage` and the other for `currency`, it might have worked better, but probably not.

Two (untested) thoughts about how to get this to work (and it *is* a good attempt to solve the problem of entering multiple values at a time):

1. You can try to see if setting all the other parameters as lists will work as well. But this still might have the problem of setting one parameter to a number and the other to a percentage.
2. Look into [Developer Composite Entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#dev_composite). This will let you create a composite entity that contains both the name and value and treat it as a single Entity. Then you can specify, in your sample phrase, that you will accept a list of these Entities.

Comment: And if #2 works, you may wish to document it as an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488991/multiple-dialogflow-commands-asked-at-same-time

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the first though and set all the other parameters as lists, but I had to write a back end code to extract correct value for each parameter.